# Why Django registration-redux custom form field not showing up in the form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to build a custom user registration form in Django which will do two things 1) use email field as username field 2) add an extra company_name field to show up in the form. I can successfully achieve first goal of using email as username but the second field is not showing up in the form when I do /accounts/register.

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from datetime import datetime    


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):

        def _create_user(self, email, password, company_name, **extra_fields):
            if not email:
                raise ValueError('The Email must be set')
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            user = self.model(email=email, company_name=company_name, **extra_fields)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user

        def create_superuser(self, email, password, company_name, **extra_fields):
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

            if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
                raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
            if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
                raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

            return self._create_user(email, password, company_name, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
```

Setting.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'usersignups.User'
```

How can I bring company_name in [this registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXhys.png)?

Answer (score 0):

In models.py define a new model of company details

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class company(models.Model):
   userkey = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
   company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In forms.py

```
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
 from .models import company

 class companyForm(RegistrationForm):
   company_name = forms.CharField(label='label here', max_length=50)
    class meta:
      model = company
      fields = ['company_name']`
```

And then create a custom view to render **compayForm** and save it
Hope it helps you. For me it works fine